# Wordpress Plugin requirement

Tags: wordpress

I have a requirement form my client.

He needs a registration form which should be integrated to his site where the user will come and register for that particular event. 
Can any one help me what plugin can i use to do this ?? i used http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/event-registration/ plugin but it dint work, 
i need something like this
http://startupsaturday.headstart.in/event.php?eid=213, you can see from this link the people can come and register, and there name will be displayed left hand side. similar way i need to ingrate to my site someone please help me.

Thanks in advance
Harsha.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is set up a form which posts to the database and then have a table populated from the table.

If you're unsure of how to do this & want to use plugins then I would suggest using the popular contact form type plugins like [Fast Secure Contact Form](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/si-contact-form/) or [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/).

Take a look at those to figure out which you prefer & then couple it with [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/) plugin to save the form data to the database. That plugin then has short codes that you can put in to display the data.